# How to link selectInput() which contains number choices to reactive dataset?

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to link the UI selectInput() which number choices from 1 to 50 for column heads to the reactive dataset. Every other part of the below code works fine except for this one,

temp3[,input$col_num]<-as.factor(temp3[,input$col_num])

it says Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected. Below is the code,

```
 both_na<-reactive({


   source("D:/Documents/R_Projects/Data_Camp_Tutorials/
   ML_Tree_App/functions.R")
  file1<-input$file
   temp3<-read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, 
                header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = 
   input$stringAsFactors)
   # create logical set for numeric columns
   temp3[,input$col_num]<-as.factor(temp3[,input$col_num])
   temp3[,sapply(temp3,is.numeric)]<- 
   lapply(temp3[,sapply(temp3,is.numeric)], function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 
   mean(x[!is.na(x)])))
   temp3[,!sapply(temp3,is.numeric)]<- 
    lapply(temp3[,!sapply(temp3,is.numeric)], function(x) replace(x, 
     is.na(x), Mode(x[!is.na(x)])))
     temp3
     })
```

Comment: You probably haven't set the `col_num` variable. `temp3` is created when the file is selected.

Comment: no I did in UI as

Comment: selectInput(inputId = "col_num", label ="col_num", chocies =c(1:50) in UI

Comment: @ Rohit. I got the answer by trial and error method,

Comment: temp3[,as.numeric(paste(input$col_num))]<- 
          as.factor(temp3[,as.numeric(paste(input$col_num))])